# Making things responsive in css

Tags: html, css

I am quite new in web designing and i want some opinions on how specific things are usually done. I have a div (box) containing an image in my page,and once you hover it, a child div(caption) appears with the image caption.

In my regular widescreen, i accomplished this, setting the box div a height:300px X width:500px; , the image a width:100% X height:auto, and the caption div width/height:100%. 
 It works, but i want to ask, if i want to make this responsive, do i simply have to change these parameters for different media screens? Or is there another way,which makes everything adaptive at once? What is more accustomed?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Often questions can be answered faster and more accurately by providing a code sample. Please read this: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is either **too broad**, opinion based or requires discussion and so is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look into how to use % and vw/vh (viewport width units/viewport height units) as opposed to pixels because if your box has its dimensions set in pixels, it will only look good on the screen you are designing for, but will not scale to other screens.

If you post a code snippet, it would be possible to show you how to go from px units to responsive units such as %, vw.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve responsiveness by setting the width of all your elements in terms of percentage or vw/vh. But this is not always handy and useful.Sometimes it shrinks your image according to the screen size(a miniature version of the desktop site will be shown even in a mobile) which is not always desired.But there are many other ways to make your website responsive.
Some ways are:

1. You can use media queries and use the max-width property to make the
   site responsive for different resolutions and screen sizes.
2. You can use [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) which you can use for creating a
   completely responsive site

If you have any doubts regarding kindly leave a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your responses! I made a fiddle of the situation i described.I am familiar with bootstrap, but I wanted to do this strictly with html/css.

```
 <div class="box">
    <img >

    <div class="caption">
    <h1>
     This is the caption
    </h1>
    <p>
    This is the paragraph
    </p>
    </div>



       .box{
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    overflow:hidden;
    height:300px;
    width:500px;

    }

    .box img{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    left:0;
    position:absolute;
     transition: all 300ms ease-out;}

    .caption{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    left:-100%;
    position:absolute;
     transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    }

    .box:hover .caption{
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.8);

      opacity: 1;
      transform: translateX(100%);

    }
    .box:hover img{


      opacity: 1;
      transform: translateX(100%);
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wrz9uxaa/1/